# PDF file link question - can I link to a different page within the same file?

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

This question is about PDF format files, not JS or HTML. Inside a PDF file, I'd like to create a link to another page within the same file. This is useful for Table of Contents type page that needs to link to other pages. But the "Add Link" item in PDF editor in Acrobat doesn't seem to have this as an option -- only the opening of web links, or "documents" (external files, not the current one), etc. Welcome any pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, that's possible.

In the `Link` tool, you first set the active area (that's where you click to go to the destination.

In a first dialog, Acrobat asks for the properties of the active area. In the `Link Action` area, select `Go to a page view`. After clicking on `Next`, you get a next dialog, directing you to navigate to the target view (page and zoom factor). Confirm, and you have set up your link…